# Can I mount same volume to multiple docker containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to share the application logs to mounted volume. 
I want to mount same volume to all docker containers to keep the logs.
is it possible? will it effect the application running on each container?

```
docker run -d  --name C1 -v /home/ubuntu/logs:/usr/local/apache/htdocs/ httpd
docker run -d  --name C2 -v /home/ubuntu/logs:/etc/app/logs my-docker-image:latest
docker run -d  --name C3 -v /home/ubuntu/logs:/usr/logs TestImage:latest
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes you can add same location as a volume to many docker containers.

Additionally you can use `--volumes-from` to mount your log directory in one container not actually running any application and then use the volumes from this container in your other containers without having to repeat the paths everywhere.

Worth a read [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)

Answer (score 4):

I'm mounting the same directory to several containers but for read purpose, not write (if your logs are written within the containers. I think that if they are writing to different files it Should work..

Comment: I wanted to mount the logs. I have many docker containers are running, but I am keeping the log file as log.txt for all services running. so How can I differentiate which log file for which service, because all log files are using the same name?

Comment: I think you can mount specific file and not all directory, and give it diff name in host: `/path/in/container/log.txt:/path/in/host/container1_log.txt`

Comment: @ItayB be careful with that because if your file gets rotated or the inode changes for whatever reason the file in docker will no longer point to the file you would expect...