# How do I both expose the port on a container to the local host AND bind persistent data to the container?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am using `dockerode` to create a new PostgreSQL docker container. I want to be able to:

1. Expose port `5432` on the local host
2. Have the container use a directory on the local host as the persistent data store

I've been able to get a working implementation that creates a Docker container and exposes port `5432` on the local host with the following code:

```
docker.createContainer({
      Image: "postgres",
      Env: [`POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres`],
      HostConfig: {
        PortBindings: {
          "5432/tcp": [{ HostPort: "5432" }]
        },
      },
      ExposedPorts: {
        "5432/tcp": {}
      },
      name: "container-name"
})
```

- In this implementation, the data is not persistent - restarting the container will always start from a "fresh" DB

  - I need to have persistent data

From reading the Docker REST API documentation (and through reading lots of community posts), I found that I need to use the `Binds` parameter. I updated my code to the following:

```
docker.createContainer({
      Image: "postgres",
      Env: [`POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres`],
      HostConfig: {
        PortBindings: {
          "5432/tcp": [{ HostPort: "5432" }]
        },
        // NEW CODE
        Binds: [
          "/path/on/host/machine:/path/on/container"
        ],
      },
      ExposedPorts: {
        "5432/tcp": {}
      },
      name: "container-name"
})
```

- However, after adding the `Binds` parameter, ***I am no longer able to connect to the database from the host machine***

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I can't figure out what `Binds` needs to be in this particular setup. Eventually, I won't need the database exposed to the local machine, but for now, I need to be able to for testing purposes. Thanks in advance!

### UPDATE 1 - 6/15/2019

I retested this with a similar setup as suggested, which really wasn't all that different from what I was already doing. However, the suggestions helped me get on the right track and understand where my error was.

It seems that the problem was happening because I was trying to reuse a directory on my local host that had already been used for a different database setup. I thought this was supported; I'm guessing there is something I am missing?

In either case, I have this working now, but I don't quite get why I can't reuse the same directory on my host machine that I was using when I start the containers from the command line.

#### Clarification

I failed to mention that I can get this working by starting the container from the command line. The problem is when trying to use `dockerode` - however, I don't think this is a problem with Dockerode, but rather with some misunderstanding I have with the Docker REST API.

I *can* use the same directory for all databases **IF** I started the containers from the Command line, *but not if I start the containers using the Docker REST API (`dockerode` in my case)*.

### UPDATE 2 - 6/15/2019

It seems there was something wrong with the path my code was generating. After I went through this a bit, it seems I simply overlooked that error. Strangely, I didn't get any errors in the container when I checked the logs - that's why I didn't think there was anything wrong with the path.

**So, for those who encounter this, it may be a simple matter of needing to fix the path you referenced on the host machine.**

With that being said, I've marked the accepted solution by mchawre - his solution was correct for the original question I asked. The rest of the issues I had were due to a bug, it seems.

(I do wish the Docker logs would have said something like "no such directory" for the container when it started, though - that would have led to a much-quicker resolution)

**Relevant Info**
I found the following info here:

> Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

- I think this is why I hit this issue, but not 100% sure yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this from my end and everything is working properly. Please refer below steps:

1. First I installed `dockerode` on my machine `npm install dockerode`.
2. Figured out my `machine ip` and `port` on which docker daemon is exposed.
3. Created `run.js` file which contains the code to run postgres container with external volumes.

```
var Docker = require('dockerode');
var dockerHostIP = "192.168.0.33"
var dockerHostPort = 2375

var docker = new Docker({ host: dockerHostIP, port: dockerHostPort });

docker.createContainer({
  Image: "postgres",
  Env: [`POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres`],
  HostConfig: {
    PortBindings: {
      "5432/tcp": [{ HostPort: "5432" }]
    },
    // NEW CODE
    Binds: [
      "/root/dir:/tmp"
    ],
  },
  ExposedPorts: {
    "5432/tcp": {}
  },
  name: "container-name"
}).then(function(container) {
  return container.start();
})
```

**NOTE:** `/root/dir` is dir on my host and `/tmp` is one inside the container.

4. Ran the js file `node run.js`
5. Postgres seems to be running and can connect to it from my host

```
$ psql postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres
psql (11.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)

postgres=#
```

6. Also checked the contents of `/root/dir` directory on my host to see if it is properly mounted.

```
$ ls /root/dir/
test.txt
$
```

Please try this from your end and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for this response! I went back and retested this with a similar setup as you suggested. At first, I used the same host machine directory I was using before, which still caused problems (this directory has data in it from other DBs that are not currently running). However, when I created a brand new directory on my host machine and mapped it to a location on the Container, persistence started working. I would like to have a common directory for all PostgreSQL DBs - how do I reuse a pre-existing directory in this setup? Or can you even do that?

Comment: If you want common dir for all postgres db running inside the container then it's possible. It seems you can mount same host directory in multiple containers that should not be a problem. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854936/can-i-mount-same-volume-to-multiple-docker-containers also upvote and accept my answer if it helped. :)

Comment: Well, the problem is that I can get this working from the command line, but not within Dockerode. :(

As a really rough workaround, I guess I could just use `shelljs`, but that's not that ideal since I don't think I can really get a reference to the container, unless I use both `shelljs` then use `dockerode` to list the containers and get the target one, but that's kinda hacky haha.

Comment: By the way, I REALLY appreciate your help on this - unfortunately, I haven't gotten a working solution yet, but I have been updating my original post with more-recent information. Mostly, that I can get this working with the command line, but not when I use the Docker REST API.

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like I may have had a bug in my code - I'm going to mark your answer as the solution since it was correct :)

Thanks a lot! I'll update my post with more info.