# docker volume during docker run

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-run

I am trying to mount library  present in the container into docker volume during docker run . The command is as below:

```
docker run -d  --name   mbus-docker -it --rm --mount source=/mbus/lib/libMurata.a,target=/mbus_volume   mbus-docker
```

I have verified by execing into the container that the library is present in path /mbus/lib/libMurata.a

When I try to mount the library on to volume.
I am getting the below error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create /mbus/lib: "/mbus/lib" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
```

Comment: When you say docker volume. That volume should exists. Your questions is not that clear.

Comment: Docker volume is already existing on the host created using docker volume create --name mbus_volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mount `/mbus/lib/libMurata.a` onto `/mbus_volume` path inside container then specify the type for mount as `bind`.

Your docker run command should be

```
docker run -d  --name   mbus-docker -it --rm --mount type=bind,source=/mbus/lib/libMurata.a,target=/mbus_volume/   mbus-docker
```

This will mount `/mbus/lib/libMurata.a` onto `/mbus_volume/` folder.

The error you got `"/mbus/lib" includes invalid characters for a local volume name` says `/mbus/lib` is invalid volume name. Because the default bind type for mount option is type `volume`. In this case it will try to create a volume locally on your system with the name `/mbus/lib` which is an invalid volume name.

Please go through [this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag).

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

If volume named `mbus_volume` exists on your host. Then try this:

```
docker run -d  --name   mbus-docker -it --rm --mount type=volume,source=mbus_volume,target=/mbus/lib/  mbus-docker
```

Comment: @zaks Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With the modified command it gives me error as " docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /mbus/lib.
See 'docker run --help'."

Comment: does that folder `/mbus/lib` exists on host?

Comment: It exists inside the container . I am trying to mount container directory into docker volume

Comment: Does the docker volume already exists. If so then you need to specify volume name in `source` and type should be `volume` ot you can skip it because default type is `volume`.

Comment: @zaks what you mean by docker volume? If you want the lib `/mbus/lib/libMurata.a` inside your docker container to be present on `/mbus_volume` folder on your host then you need `-v /mbus_volume:/mbus/lib` option in your docker run command no need for mount.

Comment: I am facing small issue. Trying to run two docker containers mounting to the same volume(mbus_volume)                                                                                                   1) docker run -d --name mbus-docker -it --rm --mount type=bind,source=/mbus/lib/libMurata.a,target=/mbus_volume/ mbus-docker                      2) docker run -d --name wakaama-docker -it --rm --mount type=bind,source=/murata/lib/wakama.a,target=/mbus_volume/ wakaama-docker       .

Comment: After running the first container the library is mounted correctly onto the volume . But when I run the second it doesnt . Should I do anything special to make volume mountable to both containers

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854936/can-i-mount-same-volume-to-multiple-docker-containers

Comment: Accept the answer, if it helped. So that other can know it.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use:

```
docker run -d  --name   mbus-docker -it --rm -v /mbus/lib/libMurata.a:/mbus_volume/libMurata.a mbus-docker
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The command create a new-folder inside container named /mbus_volume and puts libMurata.a inside it .  It is not adding library  inside docker volume

Comment: what do you mean by `not adding library inside docker volume` ?

Comment: When I inspect docker volume I cannot see anything added inside that