# Is it good practice to use a Shell Script to do 'git pull' for multiple Docker containers?

Tags: git, docker

I have a legacy project where there are multiple Docker containers in a server that are using code from the same git repository.

Currently, if there's an update on the code, I need to remote to each docker container then pull the code one by one.

For example, I need to run

```
docker exec -it {container_id} bash
```

then I execute the git pull command repeatedly.

So, I thought of creating a shell script to automatically update all Docker containers 1 time. But I am not so sure that is this a good practice.

Comment: Of course it's not good practice—repeating yourself is never good practice. But you're using Docker, so good practice is well behind you.

Comment: How about reconfiguring the Docker containers to [mount a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) from the same host directory (containing your git repo)? Something like: [Can I mount same volume to multiple docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42854936/2745495). I'm assuming here the containers just read, not write anything, otherwise you might have data corruption problems.

Answer (score 3):

An automated script to run `docker exec` is almost never good practice.

In this case, standard Docker practice is fairly clear.  All of your application code belongs in a Docker image.  You never try to update the code or dependencies in a running container; instead, you build a new image that has the new code, and then replace the old container with a new one.

So for each source code repository, put a `Dockerfile` in its root directory (if there isn't one there already).  Whenever you have a change, run something like

```
docker build -t myorg/myapp:$(git rev-parse HEAD)
docker push myorg/myapp:$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

On the system where you're actually deploying it, you can

```
TAG=0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567
docker pull myorg/myapp:$TAG
docker stop myapp
docker rm myapp
docker run --name myapp ... myorg/myapp:$TAG
```

There is a lot of supporting software that can simplify this.  A *container orchestration* tool can handle the stop-and-restart sequence for you; Docker Compose is a little lightweight for many production-level workloads, but you can just change the image tag in its `docker-compose.yml` and re-run `docker-compose up -d` and it will handle this for you.  You may want a private *Docker registry* to hold the images, and a *continuous integration server* to run these steps for you whenever there's a check-in.

There are a couple of advantages to this setup.  It's obvious from the `docker ps` output what versions of code you're actually running.  If a deployment goes bad, you can very easily revert to the previous build.  It's very straightforward to set up a pre-production environment with an exact set of candidate builds; building tests against it is some work, but you can decide to just not deploy a given image if it doesn't work.

As an additional bonus here, your images can be smaller (for not needing a source-control tool) and you don't need to put credentials to access your source control in your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

a simple shell script to execute command in all docker container would be

```
#!/bin/bash

CON=$(docker ps -aq)

for i in $CON
do
        echo $i
        docker exec -it $i bash -c 'echo \"Hello\"'
done
```