# Cannot share data between volumes on different containers on Jenkins

Tags: docker, selenium, jenkins

I am new at docker and I've been struggling with the following:

```
sh "docker network create grid${buildProperties}"
sh "docker run -d --net grid${buildProperties} --health-cmd=\"curl -sSL http://selenium-hub${buildProperties}:4444/wd/hub/status | jq -r '.status' | grep 0\" --health-interval=5s --health-timeout=1s --health-retries=10 --name selenium-hub${buildProperties} selenium/hub:3.141.59-radium"
sh "docker run -d --link selenium-hub${buildProperties}:selenium-hub --net grid${buildProperties} -e HUB_HOST=selenium-hub -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm --name chrome-node${buildProperties} selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-20200525"


sh "docker build -t ui-tests-runner ."
sh "docker run -d --link selenium-hub${buildProperties}:selenium-hub --net grid${buildProperties} -e HUB_HOST=http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub -v DataVolume5:/src --name ui-tests-runner${buildProperties} ui-tests-runner"

sh "docker ps"

sh "docker run --rm -v DataVolume5:/datavolume5 ubuntu ls -l datavolume5"
```

I am trying to get data from `ui-tests-runner${buildProperties}` container from `/src` into `DataVolume5`
I am getting 0 files when I list the contents of `datavolume5`

However, if I try to do the same thing with  `chrome-node${buildProperties}` `/home` I can see `/seluser` when I list the contents of `datavolume5` which is expected.

```
sh "docker network create grid${buildProperties}"
sh "docker run -d --net grid${buildProperties} --health-cmd=\"curl -sSL http://selenium-hub${buildProperties}:4444/wd/hub/status | jq -r '.status' | grep 0\" --health-interval=5s --health-timeout=1s --health-retries=10 --name selenium-hub${buildProperties} selenium/hub:3.141.59-radium"
sh "docker run -d --link selenium-hub${buildProperties}:selenium-hub --net grid${buildProperties} -e HUB_HOST=selenium-hub -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -v DataVolume5:/seluser --name chrome-node${buildProperties} selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-20200525"


sh "docker build -t ui-tests-runner ."
sh "docker run -d --link selenium-hub${buildProperties}:selenium-hub --net grid${buildProperties} -e HUB_HOST=http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub --name ui-tests-runner${buildProperties} ui-tests-runner"

sh "docker ps"

sh "docker run --rm -v DataVolume5:/datavolume5 ubuntu ls -l datavolume5"
```

I tried numerous things that I found online, I checked permissions and that seems fine. The only thing I can think of what's different is that the `ui-tests-runner${buildProperties}` container is hosting a repository. I don't know what else to try. I have been struggling for a few days now.

This piece of code was taken from the pipeline bit in the Jenkinsfile

Comment: why are you using the --link parameter? it is deprecated and there should be no need to use it [link to docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/)

Comment: did you try  [`--volumes-from`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volumes-from-container---volumes-from`)? Also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854936/can-i-mount-same-volume-to-multiple-docker-containers).

Comment: I did try that as well :(

Answer (score 4):

You have a race condition between these two commands:

```
sh "docker run -d ... -v DataVolume5:/src ... ui-tests-runner"

sh "docker run --rm -v DataVolume5:/datavolume5 ubuntu ls -l datavolume5"
```

The first command, with the `-d` option, will not stop. It will run the container in the background. The second command then runs while your ui-tests-runner container is starting up, and shows the folder before your tests have run.

Named volumes are also populated when first used with the image contents at that location. So when you use a different path that has contents inside your image at that location, you'll get files in the volume.

Once that initialization step is done and the volume is no longer empty, you'll only see files that are written to the volume by the process inside a container. You won't get changes from the image filesystem as images are redeployed since that path in the container is replaced by the contents of the persistent volume.

Comment: So let's assume I run the tests (which means I already have my repo folders in the ui-tests-runner container). I tried to `sh "docker run --rm -v DataVolume5:/datavolume5 ubuntu ls -l datavolume5"` at the end and I still didn't see any content. On the other hand when, I have a function that downloads files at one point so when I do the same thing with `chrome-node${buildProperties}` it shows me the downloaded files after the tests are done uisng the same logic as I explained in the second example for the mentioned container

Comment: I don't understand why if I use the exact same logic, I try to list the contents of my datavolume5 in two very similar situations: using `chrome-node${buildProperties}` container or `ui-tests-runner` . I can see the contents of one but not the other and the commands and options are basically the same for both

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're creating DataVolume5 as a named volume, using
`docker volume create`.
In which case you don't need to specify the absolute path,  but `docker volume inspect DataVolume5` will give you the path.

Try using a specific host directory as the shared volume instead.

```
docker run -d -v myVolume:/src ui-tests-runner
```

Comment: I tried with `mkdir` as well and I still cannot see the files. I must stress that with I can share the files from the first container `chrome-node${buildProperties}` and I am doing it in the exact same way

Comment: Try adding new files to the local dir and check if they're visible inside the container and vice-versa.

Answer (score -1):

1. first check **DataVolume5** containes something after running ui-tests-runner command
2. in the command docker run --rm -v **DataVolume5**:/datavolume5 ubuntu ls -l datavolume5
   give absolute path of **DataVolume5**

Eg. docker run --rm -v /abs-path-to-directory/**DataVolume5**:/datavolume5 ubuntu ls -l datavolume5

Comment: DataVolume5 is a nealy created volume (I just didn't add that code bit) and if it works with one container without adding the absolute path why wouldn't it work with the other?

Comment: 1. That's why i want you to check step 1.
2. ls from inside container for the volume of host without absolute path is not listing files. so give absolute path.

Comment: How do I know its absolute path?

Comment: This ```/abs-path-to-directory/DataVolume5``` is the directory on your host machine. You should know the absolute path. Else do a ```find``` command to know the absolute path of the directory