# How to reduce the size of the Image docker container of PHP (Symfony)?

Tags: php, linux, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I have a project for studying at the PHP Symfony. There is a docker file. Tell me how to reduce the size of the image.In this docker file, I install the PHP + packages, then copy the source code and install additional libraries through the composer I tried to do it without Ubuntu, but the size is still large. I don't have much experience writing docker files. Please help.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG PHP_VERSION=7.2
ARG USER=${USER}
ARG GROUP=${GROUP}

ENV TZ=Europe/London

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php \ 
    && apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg2 \
    && wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list \
    && apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
      net-tools \
      mc \
      vim \
      ca-certificates \
      librabbitmq-dev \
      zlib1g-dev \
      libssl-dev \
      openssl \
      libmcrypt-dev \
      libpng-dev \
      libgd-dev \
      zip \
      unzip \
      libicu-dev \
      curl \
      supervisor \
      nginx-full \
      filebeat \
      cron \
      nano \
    && wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.focal_amd64.deb \
    && apt-get install -y ./wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.focal_amd64.deb  
      
RUN apt-get install -y php${PHP_VERSION}-fpm \ 
    php${PHP_VERSION}-common \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-pdo \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-mysql \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-zip \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-iconv \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-gd \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-opcache \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-amqp \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-mbstring \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-bcmath \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-intl \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-curl \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-xml \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-dom \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-apcu

RUN useradd www && usermod -G www-data www

RUN mkdir /var/run/supervisor
RUN chown -R www.www /var/run/supervisor

COPY docker_conf/backend/supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
COPY docker_conf/backend/supervisor/conf.d /etc/supervisor/conf.d
COPY docker_conf/backend/entry-point.sh /entry-point.sh
COPY docker_conf/backend/wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh
COPY docker_conf/backend/generate_jwt_keys.sh /generate_jwt_keys.sh
COPY docker_conf/backend/create_var_dir.sh /create_var_dir.sh
COPY docker_conf/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
COPY docker_conf/backend/cronjobs/crontasks /etc/cron.d/crontasks

RUN ln -s /usr/sbin/php-fpm${PHP_VERSION} /usr/sbin/php-fpm
RUN mkdir /run/php/ && chown www-data.www-data /run/php

COPY docker_conf/backend/www.conf /etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
COPY docker_conf/backend/php.ini /etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/fpm/php.ini
COPY ./ /var/www/html

RUN mkdir /var/www/html/public/images 
RUN mkdir /var/www/html/public/import
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && cd /var/www/html \
    && composer install

RUN chmod 0777 /etc/cron.d/crontasks
RUN chmod +x /entry-point.sh
RUN chmod +x /generate_jwt_keys.sh
RUN chmod +x /create_var_dir.sh
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh

RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontasks
CMD ["cron", "-f"]

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
```

Comment: this looks more like the installation script for a new laptop than a dockerfile. Unfortunately there are so many things to say about this that I am not sure they would even help. Please read the Docker documentation to undrestand what Docker is actually used for. Top 3 things I see: vim in container?? the container should have 1 running process, not a cron job. for php there are already built images (https://hub.docker.com/_/php)

Comment: @Mihai - thanks, I have already started working with the documentation.

Comment: what @Mihai said plus whenever you are in doubt you can also look at one of image analysis tools which will help you explain what is going on and which layers add most to the final image size and such. For instance (https://github.com/wagoodman/dive). Or use multistage builds and such. Maybe a quick look on this article (https://towardsdatascience.com/slimming-down-your-docker-images-275f0ca9337e).

Hope it helps!.

Answer (score 0):

Image should only have libraries that can execute the application without manual intervention to achieve immutability of the container. You are downloading a lot of libraries e.g. vim, nano, that will require getting into the container and manually running them.

Also, try to break the dockerfile based on container use-case. No need to put the php app, filebeat and nginx server on same container.

See also: [Can I mount same volume to multiple docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854936/can-i-mount-same-volume-to-multiple-docker-containers)